# Javascript client side only forms authentication

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, backbone.js, forms-authentication

I've started using backbone.js with ASP.NET MVC 3 lately.
My server exposes a RESTfull API that my website works against.
Meaning - the authentication works with a dedicated "authenticate service".
authentication token for the user stored in client cookie.
No forms authentication, Server is stateless, no session.

How do I implement a client only "Forms authentication" alike mechanism 
(With 'return url' and all) ?

Is there any javascript framework for that ? or should I implement all the routing, cookie testing and validations manually ?

Answer (score 0):

I implemented something similar at one point, though with a java backend. The solution consisted of:

- Server checks that there is an authenticated session for all calls, returns 401 Unauthorized if there is no valid session with logged in user
- I added a global jQuery.ajaxError handler, that checks the http code of the error, if it's 401 I used backbone routing to show the login screen
- Login screen implemented with backbone view, on submit I send a ajax request to server, server checks credentials and creates session

The advantage of this approach is that I could use normal session / cookie handling on the server like in any app and only have authentication code in one place on the client.

Comment: How do you implement the "Forms Authentication" mechanism? Meaning: When a user tries to access an inner page in your web site but needs to be redirected to the login screen and after log in send him back to the original page ?

Comment: You're using backbone, so I assume it's a single page app, right? So the "page" you are talking about are is a route in backbone routing mechanism. I would just store the current route when the error handler is fired and redirect the user there when authentication is done.